# How to make links between external pages in the main page dynamically using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have 3 external pages (`inicio.php`, `perfil.php` and `produtos.php`). And I would like them to appear dynamically and respective in `#contaMenuEsq` as I click in the `"li"`.

I would like to use jQuery because my intention is to use `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` effects when navigating between these 3 links.

index.php

```
<div id="contaMenuDir">
  <div id="contaMenuOpcoes">
    <ul>
      <li id='inicio'>Inicio</li>
      <li id='perfil'>Perfil</li>
      <li id='produtos'>Produtos</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="contaMenuEsq"></div>
```

Thank for your help in advance.

Comment: yes i am trying the suggest from @Joseph

Comment: My question was asked before that answer was given, and is directed on what you have tried **before** any answers were given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked out jQuery [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) and [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)?

```
$('#contaMenuDir').on('click','li',function(){
    var text = this.attr('id');
    $('#contaMenuEsq').load(text+'.php',function(){
        //run fade here
    });
});
```

I suggest you read about [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) instead. It gives you more control over the actions after dynamically loading the content.

Comment: yes, but i would like to use fadeIn and fadeOut also. And i couldnt engage .load() with fades.. by the way i couldnt really understand ur code.

Comment: @Andre `load()` allows a callback, use it to run the fade.

Comment: @Joseph thanks for ur help, i forgot to put the id of each "li" is that necessary? couse i couldnt understand this part of ur example: `$('#contaMenuEsq').load(text+'.php',function(){
        //run fade here
    });`
how do i identify each of "li"?

Comment: Ok! got it. thank you very much. I will ready about get() also.

Comment: Typically you'd use an anchor for each link and read the src attribute in the click event.

Comment: @Andre i suggest you use something like an `id`, `class` or `data-*` to indicate the page name. since you didn't place any in the post, I assumed to use the text.

Comment: i updated my post! Cause actually i forgot to put the id. Could u update urs assuming that i am using the id please?

Comment: @Joseph thanks a lot.. could u insert the fades part please? just for 1 example.. to see what i am doing wrong here